# How to test a React app on mobile when warnings hide the URL in terminal?

Tags: reactjs, testing, terminal, responsive-design

How to test a react app on different devices when there are warnings in the terminal?

I want to test out my recat app on my mobile phone but the URL in the terminal is hidden by warnings instead.

Is there any way that i can ignore and disable these warnings and reaveal the URL that can be used to launch react app on my phone?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can stop displaying warning this way:

Modify the "start" script to include the --no-warnings flag in the package.json file like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start --no-warnings"
}
```

Save the package.json file and re-run React app using "`npm run start`" command.

Let me know, if you have doubts.

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

the warnings were thrown by **Eslint** extension in visual studio code, it can be disabled by disabling the eslint from the extensions tab.

Thank you everyone who took time to answer the question, I appreciate it :)